# sometimes だけ gets mildly confusing..

Tags: grammar, usage

If someone says それだけ、食べないでください, does it mean:

1. Please don't eat only that [eat other things too!]

   or
2. [You can eat anything you like but] only that, please don't eat it.

---

What about それだけ、たべてください?  Does it mean:

1. Please eat only that [and don't eat anything else].

   or
2. [I don't really care if you eat anything else but] only that, please eat it.

Comment: That seems terribly ambiguous to me without context or voiced stress... -_-;;

Comment: do you mean the phrase  それだけ、食べないでください could mean either 1) or 2) depending on context/voice stress?

Comment: The `、` makes this pretty ambiguous IMO. If you read this with a pause after and/or stress on だけ, I'd say it means *"don't eat that"*. Without the pause/stress I'd read this as *"don't eat only that"*. Have you seen this *written* like this or just heard it? Do you have more context?

Comment: i've not got context though. i read it here: http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/amount which sparked off this question..

Comment: That's actually quite different, there it says それだけ**は**.

Comment: This is the least of the confusing usages of だけ...

Comment: @istrasci what do you mean?

Comment: I'm thinking of several grammar constructs such as 〜だけに and 〜だけあって where (at least to me) it doesn't translate as "only".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is really ambiguous and depends on how it's stressed/paused:

> それだけ食べないでください。
> "Please don't eat *only* that."
>
> それだけ、食べないでください。
> "Please don't eat that. (Eat anything else.)"

The actual sentence seems to have been this though:

> それだけは、食べないでください。
> 　　　　^

That marks それだけ as the *topic*, which clearly means *"Please don't eat that."*

Comment: heys btw is it true that even if there is a comma (それだけ、食べないでください), it is still ambiguous?

Comment: In your second sentence, is だけ just a "stresser"? In other words, it just puts emphasis on それ.

Answer (score 4):

As the comments to the question state, I guess it's just very ambiguous. Real life would probably provide you with something like "everything else is ok, but…" or "if there is no other choice but to do so, then…"

Anyway, without context, for the first sentence, I would lean towards "please don't eat this one" ("it's for the boss").

For the second sentence, however, it just seems a bit weird to say "please only eat that" :)
One would rather say "それだけ食べていいですよ" (you may only eat this), so I would understand "at least, eat that".